# getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) not working in some Android 9 and 10 devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

The below code shows the `camera Intent` and corresponding `onActivityResult` code. It works fine in most devices but in some Android 9 and Android 10 devices the `var_Bitmap` is null because the pictureFilePath is empty. Is this `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` works in all devices? or is it because of any other issue?

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagefile=null;

        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        try {
            imagefile = File.createTempFile("pic", ".jpg", storageDir);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pictureFilePath = imagefile.getAbsolutePath();
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.xyz.xyz.fileprovider",
                imagefile);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

onActivityResult

```
 File imgFile = new  File(pictureFilePath);
            if(imgFile.exists()) {
                var_imageview_browse.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
                var_imageview_browse.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                var_Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFilePath);
                imgFile.delete();

                if (var_Bitmap == null)
                    var_textview_er.setText("An error occurred.");
                else {
                    var_Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(var_Bitmap, INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, false);

                 
            }
```

Comment: Are you saving `pictureFilePath` in the saved instance state `Bundle`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Could you please provide an example? i am not able to understand it. I declared pictureFilePath as global variable.

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) shows saving the `File` in the saved instance state `Bundle`. Your app's process can be terminated at any time when your UI is in the background, including when the camera app is in the foreground. When your process is terminated, global variables (and everything else) in your process is lost. The saved instance state `Bundle` helps retain data in this case.

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` If there is an exception you continue as if everything went allright. Instead you should display a toast to inform the user and return/stop.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks, i recreated the issue as per your suggestion by keeping UI in background then activating it again. Can i provide the answer giving credits to you and accept the answer to close this question. Or would you prefer to answer it and i can accept it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, just another thought, i found SharedPreferences is much easier to use for this purpose to save pictureFilePath. What is your opinion on it?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is for values that you want to use days, weeks, and months from now. If you want to use this image path for that long, then perhaps it is a reasonable solution, though more for the long-term storage -- having it survive process termination is a useful side-effect. However, if you do *not* want to use the image path for that long, and you just need it to survive this sort of process termination, then IMHO `SharedPreferences` is not a good solution.